# TV series in which bunch of teenagers were trapped inside magic world having Dragons

Tags: story-identification, tv

Long ago I used to watch a cartoon TV series which I almost forgotten. In that, a group of teenagers somehow ported to a magic world from an amusement park. There they needed to save themselves from dragons and an evil magician. Fortunately, they got awesome powers in that world. e.g. Toy bow/arrows became deadly and a girl was able to shake ground using her club. Their goal (other than survival) was return to own world.

Once they returned to own world using a roller coaster ride. The city was probably Tokyo (not sure). The magician and dragons also came after following them. Unfortunately, their powers stopped working in this world. The leader of the group (a blonde boy) run towards a telephone booth to call police, but he didn't had money. Not exactly in mind that he somehow called police or not. It's also not in my mind that police came or not (after call or seeing unusual activities). But, the magician and dragons were unstoppable. So, teenagers lured them by continuing their roller coaster ride and got trapped in the magical world again. And, their powers started working again.

Can you please identify the TV show? I want to watch it again.

Comment: "I want to watch it again." I wouldn't recommend that to my worst enemy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like [Dungeons and Dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(TV_series)). The opening shows a group of multi-ethnic Americans being catapulted into a fantasy world via a roller coaster.

[image]

Comment: Wow.. Thanks.. Recognized the characters from photo at Wikipedia. Kiss you!

Comment: I. Loved. That. Show.

Comment: **DC Comics** published a few D&D series when they had the licence and in one issue an adult **Presto**, from the D&D cartoon, was seeking apprenticeship with **Elminster** the Mage.  I believe it was some one-shot special called **"Grand Tour of the Realms"** or something.  You may recall _The Realms_ are where the characters from the cartoon were stranded, now known as _The Forgotten Realms_.

Comment: Gygax & Co. were planning a second series, one that was more sensible and adult--the characters would be performing using their own abilities, not super characters due to their special magic items.  But TSR was on the brink and Gary had to return to Geneva WI to try to get things back under control, so it never came to fruition.